# Passing variable to template and usage in a condition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a template that, based on an incoming dynamic parameter, runs a specific job or not. However it does not seem to be possible to define a `parameter` in a job template that is dynamically populated by a variable from earlier in the pipeline. Conditions are not supported on templates otherwise I could simply place them there.

This is the template `job-template.yml`:

```yaml
parameters:
 - name: conditionString
   type: string

jobs:
  - deployment: Job
    # This expands at compile time resulting in the string '$[ variables.conditionString ]' which does not work
    condition: and(succeeded(), contains('${{ parameters.conditionString }}', 'someValue'))
```

```yaml
stages:
  - stage: Setup
    # Variables are defined inside here somewhere

  - stage: DoJob
    dependsOn: Setup
    # The variable is set based on output from the Setup stage. This works fine at runtime.
    variables:
      conditionString: $[stageDependencies.Setup.SetupJob.outputs['setVar.conditionString']]
    jobs:
      - template: job-template.yml
        # Conditions are not allowed here so they must be placed inside the template or on the job level.
        parameters:
          # How can I pass a dynamic variable through here
          conditionString: $[ variables.conditionString ]
```

What I want to do is conditionally run the job based on a dynamic variable from another stage in a reusable way. I have multiple environments that run the same jobs with minor parameter differences and would like to avoid duplicating entire stages multiple times in order to make it work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think **it’s not possible to pass runtime variables as template parameters.** > Template parameters are evaluated at compile-time and can only accept compile-time expressions.

One way to achieve conditional job execution is by using runtime expressions in the `condition` field of the job itself. You can use the `dependencies` context along with the stageDependencies function to access output variables from previous stages and use them in your condition.

Here’s an example:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: Setup
  jobs:
  - job: SetupJob
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=conditionString;isOutput=true]someValue"
      name: setVar

- stage: DoJob
  dependsOn: Setup
  jobs:
  - deployment: Job
    condition: and(succeeded(), contains(dependencies.Setup.outputs['setVar.conditionString'], 'someValue'))
```

Explanation: The `DoJob` stage depends on the `Setup` stage and uses its output variable `conditionString` in its condition. The Job deployment will only run if the value of `conditionString` contains `'someValue'`.

Comment: Hi @Nedry and thanks for the reply. I think I found a workaround that makes this possible. The problem I want to solve is that I really don't want to duplicate job definitions for each environment. Using my answer above I am able to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I did some experimentation and I think that because templates are expanded inline I can actually use external variables to do this.

I really don't like having "magic" variables appearing in templates, but it does make dynamic conditions inside templates possible.

In the template I can apparently do this:

```yaml
jobs:
  - deployment: Job
    # Here I can use "variables.conditionString" because the template is expanded within the "DoJob" stage below.
    condition: and(succeeded(), contains(variables.conditionString, 'someValue'))
```

And from the main pipeline I can then do this:

```yaml
stages:
  - stage: Setup
    # Variables are defined inside here somewhere

  - stage: DoJob
    dependsOn: Setup
    variables:
      conditionString: $[stageDependencies.Setup.SetupJob.outputs['setVar.conditionString']]
    jobs:
      # This is expanded in-line which means it runs with the variable context defined above.
      - template: job-template.yml
```